# Pie chart, annoying question

Tags: statistics

I encountered this question and it blew my mind completely , having no idea, I had to come here.

Here is the profits earned by some company over some year :

[image]

Now the question goes like :

> The ratios of the expenditures and incomes in the year 1992, 1994 and
>   1996 are given to be 6:5:8 and 2:3:4 respectively. The ratios of the
>   income in the year 1996 to the total expenditure in the years 1992 and
>   1994 is ?

**BTW** could I have done $2x-6y =24$ to form an equation? (where $2x$ is income in year 1992 and $6y$ is expenditure of company in year 1992), book seems to do that but my mind is upside down seeing it, $2x-6y$ is magnitude and $24$ is the angle in degree , how could such relation exist I wonder?

Comment: I wouldn't invest in this company ... they went 800 years without making a profit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Each degree in the pie chart stands for some unit of money; rather than give that unit of money a name or quantity, I'm just going to use "degree" as the unit here.)

The profits in those three years are 24°, 60°, and 72°. Let the expenditures in those three years be $x$, $y$, and $z$; then the incomes in those three years are $24°+x$, $60°+y$, and $72°+z$. So we're given that
$$
\frac xy = \frac65 \quad\text{and}\quad \frac yz=\frac58
$$
and
$$
\frac{24°+x}{60°+y} = \frac23 \quad\text{and}\quad \frac{60°+y}{72°+z} = \frac34.
$$
This is more than enough information to find the values of $x$, $y$, and $z$ (in these arbitrary degree units). Then the question is asking us to compute
$$
\frac{72°+z}x \quad\text{and}\quad \frac{72°+z}y
$$
or possibly (hard to tell)
$$
\frac{72°+z}{x+y};
$$
either way you can calculate that given the known values for $x$, $y$, and $z$.

Comment: I am still confused how can one write "24°+x" , 24 degree is just an angle and x is total expenditure , how can we add two diff. quantities? . Thanks for answering the question :) . Also please read the "BTW" in my question :)

Comment: If you want $x$ to be in dollars, that's fine, but then you have to convert the angles into dollars. And they don't tell you how many total dollars the pie chart represents. So you have to make up notation, like $T$, to represent that quantity ... and then convert 24° into $24°\times T/360°$ dollars ... and do that with all the angles. It works fine, and all the $T$'s cancel in the end. I was just wanting to avoid that complication.

Comment: As for your BTW, I don't understand why you'd call the income in 1992 $2x$ instead of $x$. I mean, it's totally valid (if you're consistent when you use that quantity in other equations). Just seems a bit strange to me.